# what is the difference between ** and ^ in PHP?

Tags: php, operator-keyword, difference

I've got some problems of understanding, when I use the operator ** in this operation :
echo 8 ** 1 = 8 ;
and when I use ^ I obtain a different result :
echo 8 ^ 1 = 9 ;

Is there any difference that we have to consider in using PHP ?

Comment: `**` is Exponentiation, `^` is a bitwise exclusive OR.

Comment: You should check the manual: [**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and [^](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Answer (score 1):

The operator ** is for Exponentiation.

```
8**1 = 8 (8)
8**2 = 64 (8*8)
8**3 = 512 (8*8*8)
```

The operator ^ is for comparate bit to bit

Comment: I change my answer thanks

Comment: Thanks Agustin for your answer !